# How to boot from another computer's hard drive?

Tags: linux, boot

**Situation:**

1. A desktop computer with good hardware resources but very restricted access rights (Linux system). Data on the hard disk is not interesting for us.
2. A notebook computer with old hardware but full access rights.

**Wanted:**

To exploit desktop hardware resources to work with old notebook operating system, software, data, etc. That is, we want to boot from the notebook's hard disk.

**Problem:**

How to connect the notebook physically for the desktop to be able to boot from the notebook hard disk?

Comment: Removing the harddisk and placing it into the desktop is not an option?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with [Remote Desktop Connection](http://wiki.linuxquestions.org/wiki/Remote_desktop_connection).

> - to support a user on a remote computer
> - to train a user on a remote computer
> - if the remote computer is part of a company network and you are connected via VPN
> - if you have a task that needs to be completed on the remote computer
> - if the remote computer is your web-server (or another server)

Read more: http://wiki.linuxquestions.org/wiki/Remote_desktop_connection#ixzz0t54VkbUu

Comment: This method will probably not be preferable, since it does not allow the users to take full advantage of the desktop's hardware capabilities with the notebook's OS.

Comment: i dont think thats what the op is looking for. still seperated machines/data/software.

Answer (score 1):

Most modern desktops can boot from USB, so you'll want to connect the notebook's hard drive via a USB to SATA/IDE adapter.  These can be found from NewEgg.  For example, try [this](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16812156017&cm_re=usb_to_ide-_-12-156-017-_-Product) one!

Answer (score 0):

If the notebook is a Mac you could try Target Disk Mode.  This would allow you to connect the laptop to the PC via FireWire and access its drive like an external hard disk.